# Expand/Collapse is set to Expand on page load when section is already expanded

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

On documentation topic pages, the expand/collapse button on the Examples section is set as Expand when a page is loaded, when the examples are already expanded:

[image]

Resulting in a user having to click the Expand/Collapse button twice to collapse the section. Afterwards, the button works as expected.

Comment: They actually aren't all expanded; if you scroll down you'll find just the top three are. However since what we see at the top of the page is that the examples appear to be expanded, I agree that the button by default should be "collapse all examples" (unless perhaps only one example is expanded).

Comment: @Pluto - ah, so it is. When I posted this there wasn't many examples on the topics I looked at, so I thought it might have been a bug.